# Finding list of Russian military officers from same unit as cousin's grandmother's cousin killed 1911-1915

Tags: military-records, russia, world-war-1, ukraine

Can someone please tell me where I can find a list of Russian military officers, who served in the same unit as Pavel Nikolaevich Veselovsky, and who was killed between 1911 and 1915?

The list will need to either need to be in English, or translatable into English onscreen.

Comment: What unit did Pavel Nikolaevich Veselovsky serve in?

Comment: According to his Wikipedia article: Colonel of the 76th Kuban Infantry Regiment , World War I hero, member of the White Movement .

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87